# Integrate google map with angular4 without any package.

Tags: angular, google-maps

I have to try google map integration with any package. My requirement is:- 
Click on the map under this area all area is selected with one zip code. And the area is a highlight.

Component.ts:-

```
declare var google: any;
ngOnInit() {
let markers : any = [];
  let Latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.713956, -74.006653);;
  let mapProp = {
       center: Latlng,
       zoom: 5,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), mapProp);

  google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'click', function(event) {
     let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: this.map
     });
     markers.push(marker);
     console.log(markers);
     console.log(event.latLng);
  });
}
```

Component.html:-

```
<div id="gmap"></div>
```

Component.sccs:-

```
#gmap {
 height: 300px;
```

}

Please tell us how it is possible.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Why don;t you want to use Angular Google Maps?

Comment: Because I have already used google autocomplete and I haw already include script code. This package show multiple errors. If custom it is possible please write a code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at the documentation ? Everything is explained very thoroughly, and even if it's JS, you can use it in typescript.

[Here is the documentation for embed maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)

[Here is the documentation for Javascript maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map)